# How to make this .additem loop dependent by a userfor textbox value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub, which is called during an initialize event in a userform. What this does is add in job ID #'s - job titles in a combo box (`cmbReqFunding`). Right now, it loads all jobs, but I was wondering how i can make this dependent upon the leader (`txtELT`) the jobs fall under. i.e. if Leader 1 is populated in `txtELT` then only populate `cmbReqFunding` drop down list with their jobs, and exclude all others.

```
Sub LoadReqs_Cmb()
Dim rWS As Worksheet: Set rWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reqs")
If UserForm1.cmbFundingCategory.Value = "Req Reduction" Then
   If rWS.Cells(x, 7) = txtELT.Value Then 'see if column 7 in sheet is ELT value
        For x = 2 To rWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            UserForm1.cmbReqFunding.AddItem rWS.Cells(x, 2) & " - " & rWS.Cells(x, 5)
        Next x
   Else
   End If
End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way to do this? Everything I've found online deals with hard-coded values within the module window instead of how I'm loading in these values.

Comment: I don't think we can really answer this without knowing how exactly those two values relate to each other but at a guess an if statement that checks the cell value against the box value and only add those items.

Comment: @Warcupine I updated a second if statement to check to see if the column value where the ELT values lie in the sheet match the txtELT value. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, though it needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: You'll need code in a _Change handler for the txtELT value, that clears the combobox list and then conditionally re-populates it. Note that iterating x many rows on a worksheet in order to do this, could experience performance issues. Consider having two arrays with the two possible sets of values already in-memory, so when txtELT changes then you can quickly change its list by assigning to its List property instead of re-adding the items one by one, e.g. cmbELT.List = AllValues, or cmbELT.List = SubsetValues.